# How to implement FFT algorithm in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement a function in python3, but I couldn't figure out the error in the argument.Following is my code and the error:

```
def FFT1(A,n,w):

    if n==1:
        return A
    AEven=[]
    for k in range(0,n,2):
        key1= A[k]
        AEven.append(key1)
    AOdd=[]
    for l in range(1,n,2):
        key2=A[l]
        AOdd.append(key2)
    VE=FFT1(AEven, n/2, w**2)
    VO=FFT1(AOdd, n/2, w**2)
    mult= complex(-1,1)
    V=[]*n
    for i in range(0,(n-2)/2):
        V[i]=VE[i]+(w**mult)*VO[i]
        V[n/2+i]=VE[i]-(w**mult)*VO[i]
    return V

FFT1(coeff, degree, rootunit)
```

causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    FFT1(coeff, degree, rootunit)
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 12, in FFT1
    VE=FFT1(AEven, n/2, w**2)
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 5, in FFT1
    for k in range(0,n,2):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Check type of `n` variable, it seems to have to be an integer, and the error says it's a float.

Comment: Since I require n to be an integer but forcing 'class' didn't helped either. I tried  FFT1(A : list, n: int, w: complex). Is there any way else it can be implemented ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since various aspects of your FFT routine require `n` to be an integer, you should either assert that it is an integer, or coerce it to an integer.  My suggestion to to coerce to int like:

```
def FFT1(A,n,w):
    n = int(n)

    if n==1:
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `n` to `int(n)` within `range` if `n` has to remain a float. If `n` can be an int, call the recursive functions with `n//2` and not `n/2`

Answer (score 0):

The Python range() function does not accept a floating value as a step. Try converting all the floats to integers with the int() function. Basically anywhere you might be passing something like n/k replace that with int(n/k) of course this might give some unexpected results.